# RPM command repeatedly asking for password

Tags: expect, rpm

I am signing a big set of RPM packages (50000) using the below command

```
find $1 -name \*.rpm |xargs rpm --resign
```

As part of the RPM command structure, it asks for password. I am using expect script for supplying the password, like this.

```
expect -c "
spawn $1
expect \"Enter pass phrase: \"
send $2\r
interact
```

This is working very well for the first 1400 odd files. After that I am again thrown a prompt for password. This time I have to manually provide it. Like that, for every 1400 odd files this keeps happening.

I need help in understanding

1. If this password is thrown from RPM, if so, why? Does RPM store the password in cache only for a stipulated time period?
2. Assuming that so, I have manually copied the 'expect' code to provide password multiple times in my second file to provide password, still didn't work
3. Is 'interact' playing foul?

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What I have also observed is, even without using `expect`, if I simply run the command `find $1 -name \*.rpm |xargs rpm --resign`, even then it asks for password multiple times, every 1400 odd files, so, probably, nothing wrong with `expect`. If I remove 'find' and run `rpm - resign` in a single folder containing more than 10K files, it goes through fine with password asked just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the *problem* is in `xargs`. `xargs` would try to provide as many arguments to the command until the whole command line would exceed the limit. So when you have many files, `xargs` may need to invoke `rpm` for multiple times. `GNU xargs`'s `--show-limits` can "**display the limits on the command-line length which are imposed by the operating system**". For example on my system:

> # xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
>      Your environment variables take up 1689 bytes
>      POSIX lower and upper limits on argument length: 2048, 2094592
>      **Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2092903**
>      Size of command buffer we are actually using: 132761
>      #

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs.. It indeed is an issue with `xargs`. We have increased the size of the input stream of xargs by using `-s` and it works like a dream now. Thanks again